# Vue and typescript - $tours doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've installed vue-tour component.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tour
```

In vue component in mounted method I have (code in typescript):

```
  mounted() {
    this.$tours['tourTabsNames'].start();
```

And when I compile above code I get error:

Error   TS2339  (TS) Property '$tours' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance

But when I remove $tours from code and run application and stop on debug mode (F12 in browser) I can call `this.$tours['tourTabsNames'].start();` and it works. How to suppress error message in typescript while compiling code?

Comment: Did you configure vue-tour to integrate with Vue via`Vue.use(VueTour)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround, you can just access it like that:

```
this['$tours']['tourTabsNames'].start();
```

Comment: Unless tsconfig.json option suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true, this would produce an "implicit any" error

Answer (score 0):

```
(this as any).$tours['tourTabsNames'].start();
```

"As any" instructs TypeScript to ignore typing in the statement.

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any :

> TypeScript also has a special type, any, that you can use whenever you don’t want a particular value to cause typechecking errors.